# Графики на HightCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Нужно вывести 2 графика на 1 странице.
График 1 выводиться через jSon запрос c localhost/data.php, 2 график выводиться с запроса localhost/data2.php.

Как это вывести?

Вывод с data.php

```
{"name" : "Сумма платежей","category":["2017-03-22","2017-03-23","2017-03-24","2017-03-25","2017-03-26","2017-03-27","2017-03-28","2017-03-29","2017-03-30","2017-03-31","2017-04-01","2017-04-02","2017-04-03","2017-04-04","2017-04-05","2017-04-06","2017-04-07","2017-04-08","2017-04-09","2017-04-10","2017-04-11","2017-04-12","2017-04-13","2017-04-14","2017-04-15","2017-04-16","2017-04-17","2017-04-18","2017-04-19","2017-04-20","2017-04-21"],"data":[2827,2328,2613,1993,3828,9283,6214,5059,4436,5869,6034,5083,4695,6783,5157,4644,7656,5359,5244,7248,5331,7741,6883,5639,2563,2473,3302,5781,4546,9650,10053]}
```

```js
$(function() {
  init('container', 'data.php');
  init('container2', 'data2.php');
});
 
function init(container, dataSource) {
  options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: container,
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -3,
        y: 20,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
          click: function() {
          }
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: '',
    data: []
  }]
 }
 
$.getJSON(dataSource, function(json) {
   options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
   options.series[0].name = json['name'];
   options.series[0].data = json['data'];
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 
 
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX-запрос - асинхронный. Вы задаете `options` без ключевого слова `var`, она попадает в глобальную область видимости, в результате чего вы инициализируете оба чарта с одним набором опций.

```js
$(function() {
  init('container', 'https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/60ddd7a3-27fd-11e7-ae4c-e5a602c2659f');
  init('container2', 'https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/60ddd7a3-27fd-11e7-ae4c-e5a602c2659f');
});
 
function init(container, dataSource) {
  var options = { // <- обязателен var тут
    chart: {
      renderTo: container,
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -3,
        y: 20,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%d', Date.parse(this.value));
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
          click: function() {
          }
        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: '',
    data: []
  }]
 }
 
$.getJSON(dataSource, function(json) {
   options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
   options.series[0].name = json['name'];
   options.series[0].data = json['data'];
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 
 
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```